# How to style the parent item, but not the children

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a two tiered navigation for pages of my site. I would like to style the parent li with a background image when the page is selected, but not its children. I have the selection working, but either it adds the background style for all the children as well or I can get it to just select the parent, but the background won't work for the children if I am on one of those pages. Thank you for any help.

CSS:

```
div.side-nav ul li.selected a{
    color: #592D00;
    background: #FFF url(/_images/Layout/nav-arrow.png) right center no-repeat; 
}
```

url of site:

http://lltc.designangler.com/about/history

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**direct child selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors):

```
.sidebar-subheader.selected > a {
    color: #592D00;
    background: #FFF url(/_images/Layout/nav-arrow.png) right center no-repeat; 
}
```

Comment: This does not work the way I intend it to. It still styles the main link and all of the children. The alternate solution selects non of the elements.

Comment: It got me half way there. The child now displays the background (when on the page url the child is at) as well as the header instead of all of them being selected.

Comment: @Phorden Hmmm.. isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Close, but I was hoping to have only the child selected when on the same page as the child is linked to. I don't want the header highlighted as well when on a child page.

Comment: @Phorden Shouldn't `.selected` just be removed from the parent when a child is selected? As it technically isn't selected anyways? Then it would work.

Comment: The menu is created dynamically in .aspx, but I did figure out a solution which involved moving the child items into the parent ul. It was the only way I could get this to work.

Comment: Yea, it works now. I basically ended up restructuring my menu. Thank you very much for your help though. It was still helpful in getting to the end result.